# ast.literal_eval not working as part of list comprehension (when reading a file)

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to parse a file which has pairs of lines, each of them representing a list of integers or other lists. Example data from the file:

```
[[[6,10],[4,3,[4]]]]
[[4,3,[[4,9,9,7]]]]

[[6,[[3,10],[],[],2,10],[[6,8,4,2]]],[]]
[[6,[],[2,[6,2],5]]]
```

I am trying to read the file into a list of tuples of data-structures (nested lists) with the following statement:

```
with open("filename","r") as fp:
    pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) for l in lines.split("\n")) for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
```

This failed with below stacktrace, leading me to believe that the data was somewhere corrupt (unmatched brackets or something similar):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 5, in <module>
    pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) for l in lines.split("\n")) for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
  File "program.py", line 5, in <listcomp> 
    pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) for l in lines.split("\n")) for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
  File "program.py", line 5, in <genexpr>  
    pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) for l in lines.split("\n")) for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ast.py", line 62, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 0

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

So I cut down the program into manual loops and the problem was not reproducible any more. So the below code, which first reads into a list of tuples of strings and then evaluating the strings with `ast.literal_eval` works fine. The above "doing-it-all-at-once" still fails with the same error.

```
# This works:
with open("filename","r") as fp:
    stringpairs = [tuple(l.strip() for l in lines.split("\n")) for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(pair[i]) for i in range(2)) for pair in stringpairs]

# This still doesn't work:
with open("filename","r") as fp:
    pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) for l in lines.split("\n")) for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
```

Comment: In the version that works, why do you use `range(2)`?

Comment: Because each pair has exactly two lines, so the tuples are always of size 2.

Comment: Can you try including that logic in the version that doesn't work?

Comment: Could you maybe upload your file? Or does the code also fail for the example.

Comment: The traceback is missing the error message.

Comment: Indeed. Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fp.read().split("\n\n")` is leaving the final newline at the end of the last pair of lines.

Then when you do `lines.split('\n')` you get 3 lines in the last group, not just 2; the last line in this group is empty, and `ast.literal_eval('')` gets an error.

So strip this newline off before calling `lines.split('\n')`.

```
pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) 
         for l in lines.strip().split("\n")) 
         for lines in fp.read().split("\n\n")]
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, just strip the begin and end, problem solved!

```py
import ast
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("[[[6,10],[4,3,[4]]]]\n")
    file.write("[[4,3,[[4,9,9,7]]]]\n")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("[[6,[[3,10],[],[],2,10],[[6,8,4,2]]],[]]\n")
    file.write("[[6,[],[2,[6,2],5]]]\n") # evil newline
pairs = []
with open("file.txt","r") as file:
    pairs = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in multiline.split("\n")) for multiline in file.read().strip().split("\n\n")]
    for pair in pairs:
        print(pair)
```

Output:

```
([[[6, 10], [4, 3, [4]]]], [[4, 3, [[4, 9, 9, 7]]]])
([[6, [[3, 10], [], [], 2, 10], [[6, 8, 4, 2]]], []], [[6, [], [2, [6, 2], 5]]])
```

Comment: This works because there is no newline at the end of the last line. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the reason. There is no empty line at the end of file (a single linefeed after the last line, so the outer split on `\n\n` splits it into correct segments but while the first segment (and all but the last) looks like `line1\nline2`, the last segment looks like `line42\nline43\n`. Now the inner split on `\n` splits this into three parts, `line42`, `line42` and and empty string and as `ast.literal_eval` is called on all items of the split, it is also called on the empty string which fails.

The second solution avoids it as it does not iterate over all elements of the tuple but explicitly only over the first two.